# как удалять пробелы не только в конце строки, но и во всей строке(strep удаляет только в конце.)

Tags: python

как удалять пробелы не только в конце строки, но и во всей строке(strep удаляет только в конце.)

```
text = "d       d\n\n\n\n\n\nd"
print(text)
```

Хочу что бы вывод был:

```
d d
d
```

Answer (score 3):

Используя регулярные выражения, можно воспользоваться `capturing group`, состоящей из пробелов/табуляций или символов перевода строки и воспользоваться квантификатором `{2,}` (2 или более раз) и заменить найденную подстроку на `"captured group"`.

Пример:

```
import re

re.sub(r"(\s){2,}", r"\1", text)
>>> 'd d\nd'
```

Comment: В `\s`, однако, уже входит любой пробельный символ: `\n`, `\t`. Поэтому можно `(\s){2,}`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, спасибо за уточнение! Исправил ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не полон, но можно применить регулярные выражения:

```
#        один пробел или перевод строки или таб или ...
#        ----
re.sub(r'(\s)\1*', r'\1', text)
#            ---     --
#            ^       из всей группы оставляем только символ в скобках
#            символ в скобках повторяется сколько угодно раз
```

> ```
> 'd       d\n\n\n\n\n\nd'  -> 'd d\nd'
> 'd       d\n\n\n \n\n\nd' -> 'd d\n \nd'
> ```

Первый пример работает как просили, а про второй не знаю.